# New command-line path not set after transferring configuration to new user profile

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

Windows 7 with Service Pack 1, 64-bit.

I was having a problem with my user when using a program called Hugin, which, I think was due to the fact that I had a user name containing an "&", i.e. Don&Sue.  I created  a new user called 'SueandDon' and then followed the procedures in the Microsoft Support notes to copy files from the old user to the new user, excluding those files starting with NTUSER*.*.  I also copied profiles from old to new user using Profwiz.  Problem is, when I login under new user (SueandDon) and go to Command Prompt, the path is set as c:\Users\Don&Sue, i.e. path for original user?

I checked environment variables and all seems as it should be.

Not sure why the path is not being set for the new user.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "Microsoft Support notes" that you referred to?